# How to use a video file in public folder in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, next.js

I have an mp4 video file in my public folder and I'm trying to use it in a component. But it is not working and throw an error saying the video file is not found. 404. Am I doing it wrong?

> GET http://localhost:3000/video.mp4 404 (Not Found)

My code:

```
const HomeSlider = () => {
  return (
    <div className='h-screen flex'>
      <video
        autoPlay
        loop
        muted
        className='absolute w-auto min-w-full min-h-full max-w-none'
      >
        <source src='/video.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeSlider;
```

Comment: Consider restarting your server. Files added while the server is running don't show up until its restarted.

Comment: Your code just working fine for my case. make sure your video keep in public folder. Then the video name match to your component!

Comment: Thanks you guys. Restarting the server fixed the issue. I didn't know that.